# How to let end user change background image in XPages?

Tags: file-upload, background-image, xpages, attachment

Now I can import some ready made images into the image resources, present them as options to the end-user on the XPage, and then based on their selection, compute the 'style' property to update the background image. But it still doesn't let the user upload their own image as background.

Is there any way that doesn't involve image resource at all? I'm thinking of doing the normal fileupload control. Let the user upload an image as an attachment into a document and then somehow compute the style property by referencing the image in the attachment but I'm not sure how to do that or if that's doable at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you upload the image to a "User Settings" document and also calculate the filename in a field on the document  and display these documents in a view sorted by the UserName. Get the path to the document using the logged in Users name and 
Calculate the path to the image. The path should look something like this.

database path + name/view/UNID/$File/Filename

Answer (score 0):

If you use a RichText Lite field to store your image and set it to Thumbnail (with no size restrictions), then you can specify a fixed filename (on second tab of properties for field)

[image: settings on infobox]

You can then reference that attachment with a URL like Fredrick mentions.